# Executar Arquivo em PHP - JQuery ou Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

tudo bem?

Não tenho conhecimento em JQuery ou Javascript, porém conheço bem PHP x MySQL.

Gostaria de saber, como fazer o seguinte procedimento, espero consiga explicar.

Executar o **arquivo.php**, porém esse arquivo pode demorar um certo tempo para exibir todos os seus resultados, o que preciso é:

Executar o **arquivo.php** e após ele processar as informações deste arquivo, executar novamente ele ( esse tempo, não depende pode demorar de 10 à 50 segundos ). Então gostaria de fazer desta forma, porém não tenho idéia de como fazer.

Hoje tenho um código que roda a cada **X Segundos**. Porém gostaria que ele repetisse o mesmo arquivo, quando ele terminasse a execução do **arquivo.php**

Por favor me ajudem se possível...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var track_click = 0; 
var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;

var funcaoTimer = setInterval(function(){
    $('.load_mensagem').hide();  
    $('.animation_image').show();                

    var resultado = ( track_click / total_pages ) * 100;

    var new_num = resultado.toFixed(1);

    var new_num = "Exportando: " + new_num + "%";               

    document.title = new_num;

    if (track_click > total_pages -1 ) {
        $('.animation_image').hide();
        clearInterval(funcaoTimer);
        $('.load_more').show();
        $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('.load_more').text("EXPORTA\u00c7\u00c3O REALIZADA COM SUCESSO!");  
        $('.load_mensagem').show();     
        $('.load_mensagem').text("REALIZAR DOWNLOAD");  
        $(".load_mensagem").attr("enable", "enable");

    } else if (track_click <= total_pages){

        $.post('arquivo.php', {'page': track_click}, function(data) {
            $("#results").append(data);
            track_click++;
        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
            $(".load_more").show();
            $('.load_more').text("ACONTECEU UM ERRO, DURANTE O PROCESSO!");  
            $('.animation_image').hide();
            $('.load_mensagem').hide();
        });

    }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Você concorda que o arquivo vai executar na sequência em que foi escrito ? Então é só colocar um redirecionamento no final do arquivo para ele mesmo. Quando ele estiver no final do processamento, redireciona.

```
 <?php    
header('location: arquivo.php');    
?>
```

Comment: Infelizmente, tenho que exibir loading em porcentagem para que o cliente veja a evolução, veja o código... Solicitação do Cliente...